# Build multiple setups (different languages) in one step?

Tags: .net, setup-project

is is possible to build a Viual Studio setup project with different languages in on step or from commandline?

I have a setup project and want to build it in several languages. The only way i currently know is to open the project, manually change the language and build it. But this is really time consuming, as i want to create setups in three (later probably more) different languages.

Does someone know an easier/automated way to get localized setups?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still found no solution how to build my setups with different languages from commandline.
In my solution i created for every language i want to support a single setup project with the language and build them by hand/from commandline.